# influxdb/SQL get field count

Tags: sql, influxdb

I have an influxdb table lets call it `my_table`

`my_table` is structured like this (simplified):

```
+-----+-----+-----
| Time|  m1 | m2 |
+=====+=====+=====
| 1   |  8  | 4  |
+-----+-----+-----
| 2   |  1  | 12 |
+-----+-----+-----
| 3   |  6  | 18 |
+-----+-----+-----
| 4   |  4  | 1  |
+-----+-----+-----
```

However I was wondering if it is possible to find out how many of the metrics are larger than a certain (dynamic) threshold for each time.

So lets say I want to know how many of the metrics (columns) are higher than 5,
I would want to do something like this:

```
select fieldcount(/m*/) from my_table where /m*/ > 5
```

Returning:

```
1
1
2
0
```

I am relatively restricted in structuring the database as I'm using diamond collector (python) which takes care of all datacollection for me and flushes it to my influxdb without me telling what the tables should look like.

**EDIT**
I am aware of a possible solution if I hardcode the threshold and add a third metric named `mGreaterThan5`:

```
+-----+-----+------------------+
| Time|  m1 | m2 |mGreaterThan5|
+=====+=====+====+=============+
| 1   |  8  | 4  |      1      |
+-----+-----+----+-------------+
| 2   |  1  | 12 |      1      |
+-----+-----+----+-------------+
| 3   |  6  | 18 |      2      |
+-----+-----+----+-------------+
| 4   |  4  | 1  |      0      |
+-----+-----+----+-------------+
```

However this means that I cant easily change this threshold to 6 or any other number so thats why I would prefer a better solution if there is one.

**EDIT2**

Another similar problem occurs with trying to retrieve the highest x amount of metrics. Eg:

On Jan 1st what were the highest 3 values of m? Given table:

```
+-----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+----+
| Time|  m1 | m2 |  m3 | m4 |  m5 | m6 |
+=====+=====+====+=====+====+=====+====+
| 1/1 |  8  | 4  |  1  | 7  |  2  | 0  |
+-----+-----+----+-----+----+-----+----+
```

Am I screwed if I keep the table structured this way?

Comment: the usecases you have mentioned certainly makes your approach right one , also can you take all your metrics (m's) and store them as a list seperate by a comma e.g 8,4,1,7,2,0 this will help you to scale your processing power at the python process level rather than at influxdb level . and you can do all kinds operations at the process level .

Comment: adding to that , if some fields are missing while storing into influxdb then you might need to put a 0 or -1 to ignore them while doing some computation

Comment: I opened an issue at influxdb as a followup to the issues I had here:
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8492